# Rails/Heroku: undefined method `events' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I have a method that works locally on my machine but it fails in Heroku. Heroku logs say:

> NoMethodError (undefined method `events' for nil:NilClass)

I have used heroku console for an equivalent of this method and it works so there is data that supports it. The method is:

```
 def index
    @events = current_user.school.events
 end
```

I am using Devise which I believe gives me the current_user method. The equivalent, a = User.first.school.events yields the true instance value with data. The User.first yields correct data.

Here are my models:

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  #validates_presence_of :name

  has_many :events, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :users, :dependent => :destroy
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event

  def self.fetch_for_name(_name)
    school = self.new(:name => _name)
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :school

  rolify
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
end

 class Event < ActiveRecord::Base

   belongs_to :school

 end
```

It would be like me if I overlooked some simple, basic thing but if I can do this correctly in Heroku console, why would this method break. Another unrelated page works correctly on Heroku.

Comment: Why you are not using `has_and_belongs_to_many :users` in your School model? Error is caused because there is no `school` record associated to current_user. You have to check your DB foreign keys and relation login in `School` model.

Comment: Inexperience, perhaps? When I consolidate the relation as you suggest, it didn't like the :dependent clause. Yanking it works locally as before. But I'd like the capability to delete associated records. As to why it doesn't work in Heroku, I believe my relation and there is a school_id field in user. Are you suggesting that current_user and User.first are not equivalent? Is there a way to use pry on this Heroku app? As I say, it does work locally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

current_user is the user that is logged in. It doesn't necessarily mean User.first. This should be the same locally as on Heroku. If you're having trouble figuring out what user is logged in you can add this to your application controller

```
before_filter :debug

def debug
  Rails.logger.info("Current User is: #{current_user.inspect}")
end
```

And then view the output with `$ heroku logs --tail` It should show you the current value of the current_user. At the end of the day what @thesis said is correct, you have a user that does not have a school associated with it.

Comment: Yes, it is as thesis said. Even with only one user record, User.first is not equivalent to current_user. Ensuring the record was saved with the school_id means the method now works in heroku. Thanks to both.